# Train Inception from Scratch in TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I wanted to train the inception model like shown in the tensorflow github-tutorial.
Except i wanted to use a selfmade Dataset of TFRecord files.

```
bazel build inception/imagenet_train
bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train --num_gpus=1 --batch_size=32 --train_dir=/tmp/imagenet_train --data_dir=/tmp/imagenet_data
```

I changed the data directory to the folder with my own TFRecord files.
Now i´am wondering whether i´am realy training from scratch, or if this is the same thing like the "retraining the last layer -Tutorial"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are training from scratch: see the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_train.py#L180)